# Creating a reusable tab functionality using Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a simple jquery snippet for the TAB functionality.

But I want to make it reusable so that when I copy the HTML mark up it creates a tab out of that and I will only be changing the tab headings and contents.

I don't want to create a jquery plugin rather I want to achieve this using jquery and javascript.

Could someone throw some light on this please??

jsbin - http://jsbin.com/niqiline/1/edit

```
  Javascript
  ==========
  var tabs = (function() {

            function init() {

                $(".tab-content").not(":first").hide();
                $("ul.tab-headings li:first").addClass("tab-headings--active").show();

                $("ul.tab-headings li").on('click', function() {
                    $(this).parent().find('li.tab-headings--active').removeClass("tab-headings--active");
                    $(this).addClass("tab-headings--active");

                    //tabContent.hide();
                    $($('a', this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');

                    return false;
                });
            }
            init();
        })();


  HTML
  ==========
   <!-- First Tab -->
        <div class="tab">
            <ul class="tab-headings">
                <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab2">Tab2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-container">
                <div id="tab1" class="tab-content">
                    <p>ABC</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
                    <p>XYZ</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Second Tab -->
        <div class="tab">
            <ul class="tab-headings">
                <li><a href="#tab3">Tab1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#tab4">Tab2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-container">
                <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
                    <p>ABC</p>
                </div>
                <div id="tab4" class="tab-content">
                    <p>XYZ</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You want to convert jQuery functions to pure javascript so that you can use it without jQuery. Rite?

Comment: @SubinJacob I want to use Jquery and javascript but don't want to create a jquery plugin for this. Is there anyway to do so??

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP includes to load the HTML that you want. Using that and a query string in the URL. I don't think that you can do this without something on the server choosing the correct files to load for you. You can adjust the PHP file for the correct number of tabs, or create multiple ones for varying numbers of tabs, or have the PHP file output different HTML for different numbers of tabs. The code given here only works for two tabs.

Here is an example URL: `example.com/tabs.php?tab1=page5&tab2=page27`

In you HTML file add this at the top

```
<?php
    $tab1 = $_GET['tab1'];
    $tab2 = $_GET['tab2'];
?>
```

Then replace the first tab header with

```
<?php
    switch ($tab1) {
        case "page5": 
            echo "The title of page 5";
            break;
    }
?>
```

Replace the second tab header with the same but with "tab2" in place of "tab1"

Then replace the contents of each tab like this

```
<?php include $tab1 . ".php"; ?>
```

Save your HTML file as a PHP file. Take the contents of your file and place it it a PHP file. Whatever goes into your query string is the file that is loaded. Save the tab header in the switch statement. You should have a system to check if a page that you want to be loaded is set (probably in the switch statement above) if the page is not in a list of approved pages then an error should be given.

This must be run on a PHP enabled server, PHP doesn't work on anything except a server. That URL isn't very readable you can set up the server to translate readable URLs like `example.com/page5-page27` to the full URL, but that depends on what server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and it's working fine now. http://jsbin.com/niqiline/1/edit

```
    var tabs = (function(tab) {
        function init() {
                var tabContent = $(".tab-content", tab),
                    tabHeadings = $("ul.tab-headings", tab);

                tabContent.not(":first").hide();
                tabHeadings.find("li:first").addClass("tab-headings--active").show();

                $("li", tabHeadings).on('click', function() {
                    tabHeadings.find('li.tab-headings--active').removeClass("tab-headings--active");
                    $(this).addClass("tab-headings--active");

                    tabContent.hide();
                    $($('a', this).attr("href")).fadeIn('slow');

                    return false;
                });
            }
            init();
    });
    tabs($("#tab"));
    tabs($("#tab1"));
```